# Element breaks when the text gets too long

Tags: html, css

When I use the manual line break it works properly, but when I don't everything just overlaps.

This is the CSS:

```css
header {
    background: #fcb9aa;
    color: #f3d9d9;
    height:100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align:right;
}
ul {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;

}
header li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:30px;

    
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    
}

a, a:hover, a:focus,a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:inherit;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;

}
a:hover{
    color: #55cbcd
}
h1 {
    margin: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
h2 {

}
.logo{
    border-radius: 50%
}
div.nexto{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.contentl figure{
    height: auto;
    width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.contentl figure img{
    height:auto;
    width: 600px;
    transition: transform .3s ease;
}
figure img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.5)
}
div.content{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
    top: -400px;
    left: -20px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
.substance{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li><a>HOME<a></a></li>
      <li><a href="albums.html">ARTICLES</a></li>
      <li><a href="singles.html">CONTACT</a></li>
      <li><a href="artists.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <section>
    <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="contentl">
    <div class="nexto">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/ph1.jpg" alt="im1">
      </figure>
    </div>  
    <div class="nexto">
    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="date">6/7/2021</h1>
        <h2 class="name">
          PSYCHOLOGY STUFF
        </h2>
        <h3 class="substance">Psychology is the science of mind and behavior. Psychology includes the study of conscious and unconscious phenomena,<br> as well as feelings and thought. It is an academic discipline of immense<br> scope. Psychologists also seek an understanding of the emergent properties of brains, linking the discipline to neuroscience.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
  
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is in the h3 tag, I needed to add my own line break for it to work.

Also I would really appreciate some tips to make my code works better because right now everything is very confusing to me and I finding ways to simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fixed width for your h3 tag and moreover you can put the text with h3 tag inside of another tag (a

tag).

Also Use some css frameworks like bootstrap, bulma, etc to help you a making great css UI with much less efforts.